# Conditionally compile only one module at a time

Tags: rust

Sometimes while refactoring a change in one of the modules has impact on every other module (or many others), because say a type has been changed or a function parameter has been changed etc. In this case instead of changing everything and then compiling at once is there a way i can compile and run unit tests for only that particular module, tweak it to hearts content and when all is right changed the other modules etc and run the complete/normal `cargo build/test` ? Of-course one of the ways could be to manually comment/uncomment the module listings in their corresponding root module that introduces them, but is there any other way directly from say `cargo test --someflag -only_this_module` or something ?

**Explaining More:**

say I have following modules:
`a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h` where `f` depends only on `g` and `h` but rest of `a, b, c, d, e` depend on `f` (and maybe `g` and `h` but that should not matter). `g` and `h` ofcourse dont depend on anything from above. So if i make a change to `f` i want to compile only `f` and test it without changing all of them. Since `f` depends only on `g` and `h` i assume that if things are fine with these three then i should be able to test `f` even though `a, b ... e` are broken and crate will not compile if i do the normal `cargo build/test` . Is this possible.

Comment: it could be done with cfg-flags, but that would get Makefile-style messy with the dependencies

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to create multiple crates?

Comment: @Shepmaster No, no specific reason .. but they seem to make more sense bundled into one crate. But ya i need to know more on when to divide stuffs into crates and all that. I guess if there are 2 modules which depend on the rest and nothing depends on those two then putting them into a separate crate seems to be an overkill specially if they seem to fit in as a part of same crate - but ofcourse all is debatable and i'm still learning. Would be nice if we had the feature that i wanted above though. Makes refactoring fun :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run tests specifically for one module by providing it as an argument to the test binary. Cargo passes arguments to the test binary if you specify it after `--`, so something like this should work:

```
cargo test -- module::you::want::to::test
```

However, you can't *compile* only a part of a crate. Crates in Rust are units of compilation, like `.c` files in C, and you can't compile a half of it and ignore the other half.

Comment: my actual problem is i don't want the entire crate to build. While what you wrote works if `cargo build` is entirely fine, what i wanted to know was - is there a way to do this even though refactoring has not been done in other dependent modules and the build fails but i just want to test this one. Let me update the question

Comment: ah i see what you mean .. i thought i required this so much - to instruct what should be treated as a compilation unit just for this one time

Comment: This still runs tests in files in the `bin` folder.

Answer (score 7):

In Rust, the basic unit of compilation is a crate, so you can't compile a subset of a crate. How to overcome it:

- Switch the project to a [cargo workspace](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html). You will be able to [build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53134465/3160483) and [test](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-test.html#package-selection) only the specific subcrate.
- Top-down. In the root file, comment out all “downstream” modules (`// mod utils`). Compile and test the core module you were modifying. 1-by-1, uncomment a downstream module, fix it, and move on.
- Bottom-up. Replace the core module definitions with [`todo!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.todo.html) macros to satisfy the compiler, [`#[ignore]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-02-running-tests.html#ignoring-some-tests-unless-specifically-requested) failing tests, write a new implementation nearby, reimplement old definitions through the new, migrate the rest of the code.
- Duplicate the core module with its tests, like `mod utils2`. After experiments, migrate the codebase.
- Follow the motto “[Loose coupling, tight cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming))” to exclude the possibility of [stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(graph_theory)) in your project and eliminate the original problem at all.
- Execute the particular file with [rust-script](https://github.com/fornwall/rust-script):

  ```bash
  rust-script --test utils.rs --dep serde
  ```

---

The RFC to support single-file packages in cargo has been [merged](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/3424) and taken into work! 
Once the RFC is implemented, you can build and run a Rust file with `cargo <file>.rs` ✨

Comment: "the basic unit of compilation is a crate, so you can't compile a subset of a crate" - I keep hearing this, but it doesn't make any sense to me. Is this just an ideological position or are there technical reasons why this can't be done? It seems to me extremely useful to be able to suspend this rule temporarily for compiling and testing single modules. What is the advantage of enforcing that the *entire crate must build successfully* in order to run unit tests for a tiny subset of the crate?

Comment: @Hubro This would be a pretty niche use-case and likely not worth it (even though you consider it "extremely useful"). One technical reason why it might be very difficult (if not impossible) would be due to Rust's method-lookup rules: a local trait implementation can be defined anywhere within a crate, and thus may require whole-crate analysis to find an implementation and compile the single module. Other facets like Rust's module system and macros further complicate things that make the possibility to achieve that benefit less and less likely.

Comment: @Hubro, does the last option fits your needs?

Comment: @xamgore It might with a bit more effort. It requires dependencies to be defined inside the current file, so it's not a perfect solution. I will try it the next time I run into this issue. My primary takeaway though, is to split my project into sub-crates when I notice very separate concerns, such as (lexing | parsing | formatting | cli) for a code formatting tool. This should reduce my need for this feature. Honestly it hadn't really occurred to me that creating multiple private crates inside one repository was an option before now.

Comment: @Hurbo, as I can understand from [the source code](https://github.com/fornwall/rust-script/blob/main/src/arguments.rs#L91), `--dep` flag can be used instead. If you want to extract existing dependencies from `Cargo.toml`, use [yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) + some bash magic.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this.

I would list 3 solutions by order from recommended. Only first of them is idiomatic.

1. Move modules `g`, `h`, `f` to separate crates. Since Rust compiles crates separately, you can easily choose which crate to compile.
2. Made dummy target crates for testing which doesn't include other modules than those you want to test. Unfortunately, this means that `Cargo.toml` must contain only `bin` targets:

`Cargo.toml`

```ini
[package]
name = "test_compile_separate"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# This is your main executable, contains all modules.
[[bin]]
path = "src/main.rs"
name = "main"

# This is dummy build which used only to test module g.
[[bin]]
path = "src/limited_g.rs"
name = "limited_g"

# This is dummy build which used only to test module h.
[[bin]]
path = "src/limited_h.rs"
name = "limited_h"
```

And in `limited_x.rs` you write something like:

```rust
mod g;
fn main() {}
```

If you run command `cargo test --verbose --bin limited_h` you would see, that it builds only binary `limited_h` so it doesn't compile modules which weren't included into it.

Main drawbacks is that if your main crate is a library, it wouldn't work, because it would build with other targets here.

3. Use crate features and conditional compilation to exclude modules you don't like.
   `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[features]
default = ["include_a", "include_b", ...]
include_a = ["include_g", "include_h"]
...
include_g = []
include_h = []
```

And in your `lib.rs` you can write:

```rust
#[cfg(include_a)]
mod a;
#[cfg(include_b)]
mod b;
...
#[cfg(include_g)]
mod g;
#[cfg(include_h)]
mod h;
```

And when you compile your code with `cargo test --no-default-features --features include_g`, it would compile and run only module `g` and no other modules because they would be excluded by conditional compilation.