# How can I build a specific package in a workspace?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have two packages in my Cargo project. `Cargo.toml` looks like this:

```
[workspace]
members = ["common", "server"]
```

When I run `cargo build --all` it compiles all the packages.

I want to build only the `common` package.  If I do `cd common` and do `cargo build` it is working fine.

But in the root directory, if I do `cargo build common`, the build is giving this error:

```
error: Found argument 'common' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

USAGE:
    cargo build [OPTIONS]

For more information try --help
```

Is it possible to build a specific package?

Comment: You have your terminology backwards - `common` and `server` are projects within a workspace, not workspaces in a project.

Comment: @JoeClay The general terminology in the docs is that a _workspace_ contains multiple _packages_ or _crates_.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `--package` or `-p` flag to `cargo build`:

```sh
cargo build                # build packages listed in the default-members key
cargo build --all          # build all packages
cargo build --package foo  # build the package "foo"
cargo build -p foo         # ditto
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the name used in your sub-project's `Cargo.toml`, e.g.:

```
# proj1/Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "project-1"
```

If you run:

```
cargo build -p proj1
```

you'll get:

```
error: package ID specification `proj1` matched no packages
```

So don't use folder name and use package name:

```
cargo build -p project-1
```

Answer (score 1):

The first answer not work with:

```
error: package ID specification `foo` matched no packages
```

The correct way is:

### find out `pkgid` first:

```
$ cd server
$ cargo pkgid
```

> file:///dw/path/to/server:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT

### Goto workspace folder and run `build`

```
$ cd -
cargo build -p file:///dw/path/to/server:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend the answer provided: **build with the package id that can be extracted from the manifest**. For instance, I have

```ini
#Cargo.toml
[workspace]
members = [
    "crates/fpga",
    "crates/msm",
]
```

To build only `msm` I check the manifest of this module/workspace member

```bash
cargo pkgid --manifest-path crates/msm/Cargo.toml
#file:///home/maya-msm/crates/msm#maya-msm@0.1.0
```

And then I can use it in the build

```
cargo build -p file:///home/maya-msm/crates/msm#maya-msm@0.1.0
```